# Is there a native way to shift text vertically in Vim while exchanging with an adjacent line?

Tags: vim

Consider the following text file:

```
--> Foobar
    Barfoo
```

I would like to transform this text to

```
    Foobar
--> Barfoo
```

There are several ways to do this. One possibility is to use `REPLACE` mode to overwrite the first line with three spaces, and then use `REPLACE` mode.

However, I'm wondering if there's a native way to select the array text (maybe in visual block mode) and pull it down to an adjacent line.

Comment: Maybe https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2760/2174?

Comment: @Ry-, I cannot seem to get it to work on my example, but maybe I'm misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After learning about visual re-selection (`gv`), I figured out how to do this in a way that generalizes to any kind of visual selection (the first step is different depending on what one wants to select and move).

1. Select the block visually: `0vf>`
2. Yank the block into a register: `y`
3. Re-select the block: `gv`
4. Replace all the text with a space character: `r[Space]`
5. Move down a line: `j`
6. Enter Replacement mode with `[Shift]R`.
7. Paste the register contents `[Control]R"`

I recorded this as a macro and it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

While sticking to native vim has it merits, sometimes it's not worth being such a purist. Visual blocks are one area worth enhancing with plugins. In your case, I recommend [vim-schlepp](https://github.com/zirrostig/vim-schlepp) based on Damian Conway's [dragvisuals.vim](https://github.com/thoughtstream/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup/blob/master/plugin/dragvisuals.vim) plugin which makes dragging and duplication of visual blocks a joy. For more ideas on visual block plugins, just watch Conway's demo [here](https://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a binding:

```
nnoremap <silent> <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <silent> <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
inoremap <silent> <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <silent> <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <silent> <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <silent> <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

With this bind, you can use <kbd>Alt + j</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + k</kbd> to move a line up or down in normal and visual mode(for multiple lines).
This binding was taken from the [Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down).